# Create a tag for figure-drawing?

Tags: feature-request

I spend most of my time drawing portraits or figures.  How about a figure-drawing tag to encompass artistic anatomy, life drawing and figure drawing?

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any issues with this tag existing in general. I'm not sure if we have any questions that need it, currently.

The SE system is designed to remove tags that aren't used, as such, we don't create tags until they're needed. If you have a question about figure drawing, go ahead and ask it and tag it with "drawing" and ask either in a comment or flag for "figure-drawing" to be created.

If there are questions you know of on the site that you think should have that tag, please add them to your question so that we can decide if the tag works for them.